# mapply doesn't read the list items individually

Tags: r, lapply, mapply

I think I need the `mapply` rather than the `lapply` function in what I was trying to do.

This is the function that I have in mind - not working yet.

```
genctrlvars <- function(varorder, ...) {
for (j in 1:varorder)
    {
    #   print(nameofvar)
    #   print(varorder)
    # print(str(testdf))

        testdf[, (ncol(testdf) + 1)] <- -1
        testdf[, ncol(testdf)] <- testdf[, nameofvar]^j
        existingname <- names(testdf[ncol(testdf)])
        newname <- paste0(nameofvar, "_", j)
        names(testdf)[names(testdf) == existingname] <- newname
        # print(str(testdf))

    }
    return(testdf)
}
```

Its called like this:

```
mymapplytest <- mapply(genctrlvars, varorder, nameofvar, MoreArgs = list(testdf))
```

The idea being that the function is called for each of element of the 2 lists viz `varorder` and `nameofvar` - both of these lists have 2 elements. The data frame is the same for both of the lists.

So, why doesn't it run? What am I doing wrong?

The details of all of the parameters are shown below:

```
"varorder" is a list of 2 'varorder' values i.e. c(1, 1)
"nameofvar" is a list of the names of 2 the variables i.e. c("Trend", "Temp")
"testdf" is a data frame - structure is shown below :-


varorder <- list(1, 1)
nameofvar <- as.list(gsub("order", "", c("Trendorder", "Temporder")))
testdf <- list(controlvarsdfobjects[[1]])

str(testdf)
List of 1
 $ :'data.frame':   44640 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ Trend       : num [1:44640] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ Temp        : num [1:44640] NA 22.8 23 22.8 22.7 22.4 21.3 20.7 20.4 20 ...
  ..$ Wind        : num [1:44640] NA 8 10 10 9 5 2 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ Humidity    : num [1:44640] NA 77 77 77 78 79 82 85 87 88 ...
  ..$ Sunhrs      : num [1:44640] NA 8.82 8.82 8.82 8.82 8.82 8.82 8.82 8.82 8.82 ...
  ..$ Temp_Recency: num [1:44640] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

This is the error I get when run with print statements active:

```
    mymapplytest <- mapply(genctrlvars, varorder, nameofvar, MoreArgs = list(testdf))
    [[1]]
    [1] "Trend"
    
    [[2]]
    [1] "Temp"
    
    [1] 1
T    List of 1
     $ :'data.frame':   44640 obs. of  6 variables:
      ..$ Trend       : num [1:44640] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
      ..$ Temp        : num [1:44640] NA 22.8 23 22.8 22.7 22.4 21.3 20.7 20.4 20 ...
      ..$ Wind        : num [1:44640] NA 8 10 10 9 5 2 0 0 0 ...
      ..$ Humidity    : num [1:44640] NA 77 77 77 78 79 82 85 87 88 ...
      ..$ Sunhrs      : num [1:44640] NA 8.82 8.82 8.82 8.82 8.82 8.82 8.82 8.82 8.82 ...
      ..$ Temp_Recency: num [1:44640] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
    NULL
    Error in testdf[, (ncol(testdf) + 1)] <- -1 : 
      incorrect number of subscripts on matrix
```

The concern I have is that why does it print both the list item of `Trend` and `Temp` for the first element run - shouldn't it only be looking at the first element viz `Trend`?

****Edit****
I did it as a loop and it works but I would prefer to use the `mapply` function. This is the working code for looped version. If anyone can help me transform it in to the `mapply` form that would be highly appreciated.

```
orderlist <- list(trendorder, temporder, windorder, humidityorder, sunhrsorder, temp_recencyorder)  #pvorder not included yet
names(orderlist) <- list("Trendorder", "Temporder", "Windorder", "Humidityorder", "Sunhrsorder", "Temp_Recencyorder")   #"PVvorder" not included yet
orderlistnames <- as.list(names(orderlist))

for (j in 1:length(orderlist))
    {thisvarname <- gsub("order", "", orderlistnames[[j]])
    thisvarorder <- orderlist[[j]]
    if (j == 1)
        {thisvarorigdfobjects <- testdf
        }
    for (k in 0:thisvarorder)
        {if (k == 0)
            {if (thisvarorder == 0)
                {thisvarorigdfobjects[, (ncol(thisvarorigdfobjects) + 1)] <- NA
                existingname <- names(thisvarorigdfobjects[ncol(thisvarorigdfobjects)])
                newname <- paste0(thisvarname, "_", k)
                names(thisvarorigdfobjects)[names(thisvarorigdfobjects) == existingname] <- newname
                }
            else
                {k <- k + 1
                }
            }
        else
            {thisvarorigdfobjects[, (ncol(thisvarorigdfobjects) + 1)] <- -1
            thisvarorigdfobjects[, ncol(thisvarorigdfobjects)] <- thisvarorigdfobjects[, thisvarname]^k
            existingname <- names(thisvarorigdfobjects[ncol(thisvarorigdfobjects)])
            newname <- paste0(thisvarname, "_", k)
            names(thisvarorigdfobjects)[names(thisvarorigdfobjects) == existingname] <- newname
            }
        }
    }
```

This is how the final output from the looped version looks like:

```
head(thisvarorigdfobjects)
Trend_1 Temp_1 Temp_2 Wind_0 Humidity_0 Sunhrs_0 Temp_Recency_1
1       1     NA     NA     NA         NA       NA             NA
2       1   22.8 519.84     NA         NA       NA             NA
3       1   23.0 529.00     NA         NA       NA             NA
4       1   22.8 519.84     NA         NA       NA             NA
5       1   22.7 515.29     NA         NA       NA             NA
6       1   22.4 501.76     NA         NA       NA             NA
```

Comment: So, what is the goal here? That would help understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Liman <- The df that is passed as the argument to the function is the same and gets a few columns added to it with each call. The number of columns that get added depends upon the 'varorder', in this example 1 for both the list items, "Trend" and "Temp". So, this function, in this case, will get called twice adding 1 column at each call - 1 for call for variable "Trend" with column name "Trend_1" and 1 for variable "Temp" with column name "Temp_1"as the order for both of them is 1. Does that make it any clearer?

Comment: OK, I can see a bit clearer. So, the whole point is to create 2 new columns called `Trend_1` and  `Temp_1` as part of  `testdf`?

Comment: Essentially yes but this can't be hard code. It needs to be done programmatically as I have only included 2 list items each with 1 order. There can be multiple list items each with different orders. Hence, the need to do it this way!